# History feature

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a history feature which could resemble of what  an user can experience in a browser using back and forwards buttons (Chrome).

How does the following scrip workst:

- When user visit page for first time, initial view `view0` is shown.
- When user click buttons prev/next view is switched of +1/1 and history of the view is saved.
- When user click buttons back/forward view is shown accordingly.
- When user click goTo (to move to a specific view), view is shown, multiple sequential click to goTo are not registered in history.

My current script works but:
- I would like to know if a refactor can be applied to the logic, specially function `back`.
- This solution use two arrays, one for back and forward history, I would like to know if you could point me out also a completely different approach if better suitable for this task.

Notes:
I cannot use History Web APIs.

```js
(function(window) {
  let historyBack = [];
  let historyForward = [];
  let activeView;

  let btnPrev;
  let btnNext;
  let btnBack;
  let btnForward;
  let btnGoTo;
  let btnLogs;

  let result;
  let views = ['view0', 'view1', 'view2', 'view3', 'view4'];


  let logs = () => {
    console.log('historyBack', historyBack, 'historyForward', historyForward, 'activeView', activeView);
  };

  let render = () => {
    result.innerHTML = activeView;

  };

  let isViewValid = (id) => {
    return views.indexOf(id) > -1 ? true : false;
  };

  let isViewAlreadyInHistory = (id) => {
    let hasHistory = historyBack.length > 0 ? true : false;
    let isViewSameAsLastView = historyBack[historyBack.length - 1] === id;
    if (hasHistory && isViewSameAsLastView) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  let addViewToHistoryBack = (id) => {
    historyBack.push(id);
  };

  let setActiveView = (id) => {
    activeView = id;
  };

  let goTo = (id) => {
    let isValid = isViewValid(id);
    if (isValid) {
      let canSaveHistory = !isViewAlreadyInHistory(id);
      if (canSaveHistory) {
        addViewToHistoryBack(id);
      }
      setActiveView(id);
      render();
    }

  };

  let getNextView = () => {
    let activeViewIndex = views.indexOf(activeView);
    activeViewIndex++;
    return views[activeViewIndex];
  };

  let getPrevView = () => {
    let activeViewIndex = views.indexOf(activeView);
    activeViewIndex--;
    return views[activeViewIndex];
  };

  let next = () => {
    resetHistoryForward();
    let nextView = getNextView();
    goTo(nextView);
  };

  let prev = () => {
    resetHistoryForward();
    let prevView = getPrevView();
    goTo(prevView);
  };


  let back = () => {
    if (historyBack.length === 1) {
      // do not remove default view
      return;
    }

    let activeView = historyBack.pop();
    let backView = historyBack.pop();
    if (backView) {
      goTo(backView);
      historyForward.push(activeView);
    }
  };

  let forward = () => {
    let forwardView = historyForward.pop();
    if (forwardView) {
      goTo(forwardView);
    }
  };

  let resetHistoryForward = () => {
    historyForward.length = 0;
  };

  let start = () => {
    result = document.getElementById('result');
    btnPrev = document.getElementById('btnPrev');
    btnNext = document.getElementById('btnNext');
    btnBack = document.getElementById('btnBack');
    btnForward = document.getElementById('btnForward');
    btnGoTo = document.getElementById('btnGoTo');
    btnLogs = document.getElementById('btnLogs');

    btnPrev.addEventListener('click', event => {
      prev();
    });

    btnNext.addEventListener('click', event => {
      next();
    });

    btnBack.addEventListener('click', event => {
      back();
    });

    btnForward.addEventListener('click', event => {
      forward();
    });

    btnGoTo.addEventListener('click', event => {
      goTo('view3');
    });


    btnLogs.addEventListener('click', event => {
      logs();
    });
  };


  let setDefault = () => {
    goTo('view0');
    render();
  };

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    start();
    setDefault();

  });
})(window);
```

```css
#result {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="btnPrev">Prev</button>
<button id="btnNext">Next</button>
<br>
<button id="btnBack">Back</button>
<button id="btnForward">Forward</button>
<br>
<button id="btnGoTo">GoTo 3</button>
<br>
<button id="btnLogs">logs</button>
```

Comment: Is this desired behavior? Clicking on "Next" -> "Back" -> "GoTo 3" -> "Forward" leads me to "view1" because the forward history isn't pruned when a navigation event occurs.

Comment: @le_m thanks for commenting, yes it is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently don't prune the forward history when clicking on 'goto'. I assume this is a flaw.

Instead of splitting the history into a backward and forward array, I propose using a single array and keeping track of the currently active index. This allows you to simplify your logic, i.e. you can replace `historyForward.pop()` and `historyBackward.push()` with a simple `index--`.

I also suggest separating and encapsulating the logic and datastructures needed to keep track of and browsing through a history. A dedicated history module or class is simpler to understand, easier to test and can be reused.

The same can be applied to the view navigation logic.

Depending on your view/controller logic, you might want to apply the observer pattern to your navigation module or class and listen to navigation events which would then lead to a rendering of the new view.

Here is an implementation of the history and navigation as separate classes (without the observer pattern):

```js
class History {
  constructor() {
    this.states = [];
    this.index = -1;
  }
  get current() {
    return this.states[this.index];
  }
  forward() {
    if (this.index < this.states.length - 1) this.index++;
  }
  back() {
    if (this.index > 0) this.index--;
  }
  push(state) {
    this.index++;
    this.states.splice(this.index, this.states.length - 1, state);
  }
}

class Navigation {
  constructor(...views) {
    this.history = new History();
    this.history.push(0);
    this.views = views;
  }
  get current() {
    return this.views[this.history.current];
  }
  next() {
    let index = this.history.current + 1;
    if (index < this.views.length) {
      this.history.push(index);
    }
  }
  prev() {
    let index = this.history.current - 1;
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.history.push(index);
    }
  }
  forward() {
    this.history.forward();
  }
  back() {
    this.history.back();
  }
  goto(index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < this.views.length && index != this.history.current) {
      this.history.push(index);
    }
  }
}

let nav = new Navigation('view0', 'view1', 'view2', 'view3', 'view4');

let result = document.getElementById('result');
let btnPrev = document.getElementById('btnPrev');
let btnNext = document.getElementById('btnNext');
let btnBack = document.getElementById('btnBack');
let btnForward = document.getElementById('btnForward');
let btnGoTo = document.getElementById('btnGoTo');

btnPrev.addEventListener('click', event => {
  nav.prev();
  render();
});

btnNext.addEventListener('click', event => {
  nav.next();
  render();
});

btnBack.addEventListener('click', event => {
  nav.back();
  render();
});

btnForward.addEventListener('click', event => {
  nav.forward();
  render();
});

btnGoTo.addEventListener('click', event => {
  nav.goto(3);
  render();
});

function render() {
  result.innerHTML = nav.current;
}

render();
```

```css
#result {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="btnPrev">Prev</button>
<button id="btnNext">Next</button>
<br>
<button id="btnBack">Back</button>
<button id="btnForward">Forward</button>
<br>
<button id="btnGoTo">GoTo 3</button>
```

Comment: In my real app unfortunately I have to stick with double array. Nevertheless I accept this answer as I found it informative and of interest. Thanks!